# Confirmar qual contrato abrir

Tags: php, pdf, microsoft-word

Opa galera preciso de ajuda, tenho o sistema de login feito já e já tenho uns dois usuários cadastrados, quero que cada usuário tenha um contrato que no caso ja tenho os dois contratos digitalizados, quero que quando o **usuario fulanodetal** veja o **contrato1** e o fulanodetal2 veja o **contrato2**

Meu codigo é

```html
<?php
session_start();
include('verifica_login.php');
?>

<h2>Olá, <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario'];?></h2>

<h2><a href="logout.php">Sair</a></h2>
```

Tenho uma pasta chamada **Contratos** quero que cada usuario tenha acesso a seu contrato em word ou pdf, cada usuario vai ter nome do contrato igual do usuario so vai poder acessar se estiver logado, não sei como fazer a confirmação pelo painel pra verificar se o usuario.doc é igual que está logado no painel.php

Comment: salva o contrato com um identificador para cada usuário, por exemplo, `fulanodetal.pdf` fica fácil de identificar, não quer dizer q seja a forma mais correta, porém funcional

Comment: Mais no painel não da pra colocar isso pois ele vai ficar no mesm contrato os dois usuarios

Comment: Exemplo painel ele pega o usuario que esta logado e bate a informação que está no painel

Comment: então é um contrato para cada ou um para todos?

Comment: Para cada usuario é um contrato diferente

Comment: Por que o contrato já esta pronto so preciso que o cliente quando quiser ver o contrato ele entre pelo login dele

Comment: foi o que eu disse então:
Usuario1 tem o Contrato1.pdf
Usuario2 tem o Contrato2.pdf

Comment: Isso so que eu preciso confirmar so não sei como confirmar no painel.php

Comment: Quero que o usuario1 apareça quando estiver logado no painel.php apareça contrato1

Comment: Se tiver como direcionar o usuario para outro php confirmando usuario para fazer a seleção dos contratos

Comment: Ou colocar o nome do contrato no nomedocliente no caso usuario.doc e ai faz uma verificação que se o nome do usuario é compativel com nome do documento se não ele nem entra e da erro

Comment: isso mesmo q estou te falando, coloca o nome do arquivo com algo q seja unico do usuário para vc poder verificar

Comment: Tem algum exemplo de verificação encima do painel?

Comment: Não achei nem uma forma de validar, se tiver como me ajudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codigo completo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Contrato</title>
</head>

</html>


<?php
session_start();
include('verifica_login.php');
include('conexao.php');
if($_SESSION['cpf']){

    $download = $_GET['download'];
    if( is_file( 'Contratos/'.$download)){
        $filename = 'Contratos/'.$download;

        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $type = finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
        header('Content-type: '.$type);
        readfile($filename);
    }else{
        echo "arquivo nao encontrado";
    }

}else{
    echo "Você não está logado. Faça o login para efetuar o download.";
}

?>
```

Assim funcionou usando dentro do meucontrato.php

```
> <a href="download.php?download=<?php echo
> $_SESSION['documentopdf']?>.pdf"><b>Abrir meu Contrato</b></a>
```